# Post request is empty (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post

I want to send a post request and add data to the database table.

**Here is my model:**

```
public partial class PaymentMethods
{
    public PaymentMethods()
    {
        PaymentToUser = new HashSet<PaymentToUser>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? CardNumber { get; set; }
    public int? Month { get; set; }
    public int? Year { get; set; }
    public int? Cvv { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Index { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PaymentToUser> PaymentToUser { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is the Controller method that receives POST request:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddPaymentMethod(PaymentMethods payment)
{
     string result;
     if(ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         _context.PaymentMethods.Add(payment);
         _context.SaveChanges();
         result = "Added";
     }
     else
     {
         result = "Error";
     }

     return Json(result);
}
```

**And here is the JSON that I am sending via Postman:**

> {
>       "CardNumber": 2345678912343456,
>       "Month": 10,
>       "Year": 20,
>       "CVV": 322,
>       "Name": "Eugene",
>       "Surname": "Sukhomlyn",
>       "Index": 83050,
>       "Country": "UA"
>   }

**So I think all great with data, but I get the empty object in controller method on the post, where is my error?**

Comment: 2.3 quadrillion *definitely* won't fit into an `int`.  I suspect a credit card number should probably be a string, no?  Do you ever need to perform math on a credit card number?

Comment: Thank;s for suggestion @David

Comment: But it not helps with empty objects in DB @David

Comment: It's at least worth correcting so as to eliminate potential problems.  `Index` is also defined as a `string` but the input is providing a number.  When debugging, is the `payment` object `null`?  Is it instantiated but all of its properties are default values?  If so, it's also worth taking out the database parts and focusing solely on the problem at hand.

Comment: @David You may not do math on it directly. But you might be surprised to find out that a [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) is implemented for many credit card numbers. I found out about this algorithm when working on medical provider numbers in the healthcare industry and thought it was really neat.

Comment: @EugeneSukh How did you post the data? Could you show the code?

Comment: @EugeneSukh You need to add `[FromBody]` before the input parameter like this: `public JsonResult AddPaymentMethod([FromBody] PaymentMethods payment)`

Comment: Also JSON is case sensitive so `CVV` should be replaced by `Cvv`

Comment: Have you set the correct contentType?

Comment: @EugeneSukh Please Share your PostMan setting when you are posting data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting `[FromBody]` in method parameter if you are passing json from body.

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer.  I see that you are new to Stack Overflow, you can comment once you receive 50 reputation.